# Program variable spacing to align elements of printed output across rows

Tags: python, text-alignment

I'd like to better align the rows of text that my code generates as printed output. For instance, in the example text below, there is variable spacing after each month's name to align the commas at the same position in each row:

```
january   , 
february  ,
march     ,
april     ,
may       ,
etc.
```

In my specific case, the actual output that my code has generated appears as follows:

[image]

Whereas the expected output would look like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
print("À la fin du mois " + moisCourrant.nom + " , il restera " + str(numChevres) + " chèvres, revenu mensuel :  " + str(profitMoisCourant) + "$")
```

Comment: Is this spam? I cannot say if there is a question here..

Comment: Use a format string with field widths.

Comment: Try string.ljust()  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust

Comment: There is a chapter of the Python tutorial devoted to this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\t` in any string that you need alignment. The `\t` puts a tab in the string. So you can have it like so:

```
print("À la fin du mois " + moisCourrant.nom + " \t, il restera \t" + str(numChevres) + " \t chèvres, revenu mensuel :  \t" + str(profitMoisCourant) + "$")
```

Comment: That will left-align the numeric columns, and OP wants them right-aligned.

Comment: Check this out, that's the result:
https://pasteboard.co/oVWkKCMMNb3S.png